# Is there a way with the OpenTelemetry Operator Auto-Instrumentation to instrument multiple languages in the same Pod

Tags: open-telemetry

I have an application running in Kubernetes that has a pod that has multiple containers. Each container performs part of a task. Namely, one is the API (written in node.js), a backend transport (written in java), and a drive connector (written in C).

When attempting to add multiple annotations for instrumentation, we get the error:

44s         Warning   FailedCreate       statefulset/my-pod-with-multiple-containers   create Pod my-pod-with-multiple-containers-1 in StatefulSet my-pod-with-multiple-containers failed error: Pod “my-pod-with-multiple-containers-1” is invalid: spec.containers[1].volumeMounts[2].mountPath: Invalid value: "/otel-auto-instrumentation": must be unique

I know that with OpenTelemetry, you can annotate a pod to do auto-instrumentation, such as:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Statefulset
metadata:
  name: my-deployment-with-multiple-containers
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-pod-with-multiple-containers
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-pod-with-multiple-containers
      annotations:
        instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/inject-java: "true"
        instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/container-names: "myapp,myapp2"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myImage1
      - name: myapp2
        image: myImage2
      - name: myapp3
        image: myImage3
```

The above (taken from https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/blob/main/README.md#multi-container-pods), myapp and myapp2 would get java auto-instrumentation injected.

We tried doing:

```
      annotations:
        instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/inject-java: "true"
        instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/container-names: "myapp"
        instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/inject-nodejs: "true" 
        instrumentation.opentelemetry.io/container-names: "myapp2"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myImage1
      - name: myapp2
        image: myImage2
      - name: myapp3
        image: myImage3
```

We were hoping this would make it so that myapp would get Java instrumentation and myapp2 would get node.js instrumentation.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it’s not supported.

p.s. We discussed it briefly in slack and it’s something we’d be interested in learning more about the use case, if you want to create an issue in our the [operator repository](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/issues).